# java and mybatis - misunderstanding one-to-many relation - only annotations

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a two tables: Person and Dog.  You know that person may have more than one dog.
My model is:

```
public class {
  int personId;
  List <Dog> dogs;
  String name;
  String surname;
}
public class Dog{
   String name;
   int dogId;
}
```

When it comes to database it is fairly similar:

```
PersonID(PK), Name (String), surname(String)   
dogId(PK), name(String), IdOwner(FK)
```

Can you help me write select in mybatis  ?   I tried to read about `@one` and `@many`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `MyBatis` you have two options described in the [reference documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps):

> - **Nested Select**: By executing another mapped SQL statement that returns the complex type desired.
> - **Nested Results**: By using nested result mappings to deal with repeating subsets of joined results.

In your case, as you want to load the many association you must use the **Nested Select**, because you can't load a many association using a `fetch outer join` (just associations with one row fetched)

### Nested Select

In this option you should need to add a reference to the select, which loads the daya by the foreign key relationship (in your case foreign key of person), of the relationship which in your case is `dogs` in the `ResultMap.

So you should have a query which loads the `Person` table:

```
<select id="findById" resultMap="personResult">
  SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = #{name}
</select>
```

Its method:

```
Person findById(String name);
```

Then a query which loads the dogs by person key relationship:

```
<select id="findDogsByPerson" resultType="Dog">
  SELECT * FROM DOG WHERE ID_PERSON = #{namePerson}
</select>
```

And its method:

```
List<Dog> findDogsByPerson(String namePerson);
```

Then you must add the select as association in the resultmap referencing to the select by foreign key (`findDogsByPerson`). In your case is a many association, so you should use the `collection` tag instead of `association`.

```
<resultMap id="personResult" type="Person">
  <!--Other properties maps -->
  <!-- ..... -->
  <collection property="dogs" column="id_person" javaType="Dog" select="selectDogByPerson"/>
  <!-- ..... -->
</resultMap>
```

#### Annotation alternative

If you want you can use `annotations` to do it. It's almost the same but the `ResultMap` and `Select` goes above the methods. It would using the anotation `@Many` referencing to the many relationship.

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE NAME = #{name}")
    @Results(value = {
          @Result(property="name", column="name"),
          @Result(property="surname", column="surname"),
          @Result(property="dogs", javaType=List.class, column="name",
                             many=@Many(select="findDogsByPerson"))})
Person findById(String name); 

@Select("SELECT * FROM DOG WHERE ID_PERSON = #{namePerson}")
@Results(value = {
          @Result(property="name", column="name"),
          @Result(property="dogId", column="dogId")})
List<Dog> findDogsByPerson(String namePerson);
```

Comment: What about the same queries using annotations ?  It is not easy to translate it - I mean <resultMap...>

Comment: And what map it return ? (Int -> Person) where Int is Id ?
for me it is sufficient  to return dogs for exactly one (given as parameter) id

Comment: Yes I did, now is fixed

Comment: Thanks,  tell me one thing: What does column mean here:           `@Result(property="dogs", javaType=List.class, column="name",
                             many=@Many(select="findDogsByPerson"))})`   ?